# Remove columns in a matrix that have a match with the column name in R

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

I have a matrix in a R script and i want to remove columns in a matrix in R that have a match with the label.

For example :

```
A <- matrix(c(4,5,4,4), nrow=1)
dimnames(A)= list(c("row1"),c("foo","bar","alfa","foo"))

     foo bar alfa foo
row1   4   5    4   4
```

I want remove the column foo-4 because match with the label but not the column alfa-4

I try

```
duplicated.columns <- duplicated(t(A))
A <- A[, !duplicated.columns]
```

but the result is

```
foo bar 
  4   5
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
A[,!duplicated(colnames(A))]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to add that both the current answers drop the matrix down to a named vector.

```
class(A[, unique(colnames(A))])
# [1] "numeric"
class(A[, !duplicated(colnames(A))])
# [1] "numeric"
```

For `A` to remain a matrix after duplicate columns are removed, you can use `drop = FALSE`

```
class(A[, unique(colnames(A)), drop = FALSE])
# [1] "matrix"
class(A[, !duplicated(colnames(A)), drop = FALSE])
# [1] "matrix"
```

I only bring this up because it may be important if you're using a subset inside a function.